# Why is the detach method not removing the fragment associated with the old tab when I switch ActionBar tabs created with a TabListener?

Tags: android, debugging, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I tested out the ActionBar Tabs feature of Android using a TabListener as described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6uNjVEu7_Q) tutorial. The problem is that when I switch tabs, the new fragment is added but the old one is also visible. I know that a lot of similar questions have been asked on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't get any of their solutions to work. Could someone please help me find the problem with my code (shared below) or share a link to a working example?

I have checked that OnTabSelected and OnTabUnselected methods are being called at their respective events with the correct tabs and fragments. In the OnTabUnSelected method, the detach statement is also being executed for the fragment that should be removed, but the execution of this statement has no effect - the fragment content is still visible.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab aTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab A");
    ActionBar.Tab bTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab B");
    ActionBar.Tab cTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab C");

    Fragment aFragment = new AFragment();
    Fragment bFragment = new BFragment();
    Fragment cFragment = new CFragment();

    aTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(aFragment, "a_fragment"));
    bTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(bFragment, "b_fragment"));
    cTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(cFragment, "c_fragment"));

    actionBar.addTab(aTab);
    actionBar.addTab(bTab);
    actionBar.addTab(cTab);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public Fragment fragment;
    public String tag;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) != null)
            ft.detach(fragment);
    }

}
```

Please let me know if I can offer any other information that might help debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make test...

change

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) != null)
            ft.detach(fragment);
```

by

```
if (fragment != null){
  ft.detach(fragment);
}
```